# Responsive menu in css and jquery with slideDown and slideUp effects

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design

I have got some issue with responsive menu in css. Everything works when menu horizontal is, but when browser-width is smaller than 700px, then works almost everything except one detail. I want to .menu slides over .content and cover them. I tried with floating and z-index but no positive result.

Basically I need the menu to **`slideDown`** and **`slideUp`** on the click of link `Menu` for the breakpoint **@media all and (max-width:700px)**

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/dv55vvqe/1/)

```
<div class="navigator">
<div class="menu-icon">
    [MENU]
</div>
<div class="search">
    <input type="text">
</div>    
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Content

```
body, html
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.navigator
{
    background-color: #0171bb;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu-icon
{
    background-color: white;
    display: none;   
}
.menu
{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
.menu ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.menu ul:after
{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
.menu ul li
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu ul li:hover
{
  background-color: #004f82;
}
.menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: black;
}
.search
{
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0.4em 2.5%
}
.search input
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2em;
    border: none;
    background-color: #004f82;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
}
.content
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
}
@media all and (max-width:700px)
{
    .menu-icon
    {
        display: inherit;
        float:left;
    }
    .menu
    {
        width: 100%;
        float:left;
        z-index:2;
    }
    .content
    {
        z-index:1;
    }
    .search
    {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .menu ul li
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use **`slideDown`** instead `slidetoggle`. I also suggest to apply `display:none;` to `.menu` for `@media all and (max-width:700px)` breakpoint.

**Here is a jquery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function( $ ){
    var menu = $( ".menu" );
    $(".menu-icon").click(
    function( event ){
        // Prevent the default event.
        event.preventDefault();
        // Toggle the menu based on its current visibility.
        if (menu.is( ":visible" )){
            menu.slideUp( 2000 );
        } 
        else {
            menu.slideDown( 2000 );
        }
    }
    );
});

</script>
```

**Here is [FiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/dv55vvqe/5/)**

**Here is a complete jquery + css + html code**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
body, html
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.navigator
{
    background-color: #0171bb;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu-icon
{
    background-color: white;
    display: none;   
}
.menu
{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
.menu ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.menu ul:after
{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
.menu ul li
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu ul li:hover
{
  background-color: #004f82;
}
.menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: black;
}
.search
{
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0.4em 2.5%
}
.search input
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2em;
    border: none;
    background-color: #004f82;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
}
.content
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
}
@media all and (max-width:700px)
{
    .menu-icon
    {
        display: inherit;
        float:left;
    }
    .menu
    {
        width: 100%;
        float:left;
        z-index:2;
        display:none;
    }
    .search
    {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .menu ul li
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function( $ ){
    var menu = $( ".menu" );
    $(".menu-icon").click(
    function( event ){
        // Prevent the default event.
        event.preventDefault();
        // Toggle the menu based on its current visibility.
        if (menu.is( ":visible" )){
            menu.slideUp( 2000 );
        } 
        else {
            menu.slideDown( 2000 );
        }
    }
    );
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigator">
    <div class="menu-icon">
        [MENU]
    </div>
    <div class="search">
        <input type="text">
    </div>    
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
     Content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed the jquery to bring `SLIDEDOWN` and `SLIDEUP` effect

Comment: Feel free to change the `slideDown` and `slideUp` effect parameters as per your preferences. :) Hope this gives you a complete solution that you were looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `position: absolute;`:

```
.menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    background-color: #0171bb;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/dv55vvqe/3/)